# why is 'Klim' beejakshara used in krishna mantra (even though it's goddess Shakti's mantra)?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, shakti

I found it confusing to use a KLIM beejamantra in Krishna prayers even though it is for goddess Shakti and later after googling found out that Shakti and Krishna(Supreme GOD and source of all) are same according to Tantra...and ten incarnation of Vishnu(Krishna) are amsas of Dasa Mahavidyas of Shakti... Pls help get rid of this confusion

Comment: What you mean supreme ? What about other gods ?

Answer (score 2):

The beeja KLEEM is actually called KAAMA BEEJA. It is also called Kameshibeeja,Guhyakaalibeeja, and Krishna/Gopala beeja according to Mantravidhaana.

So KLEEM Krishnaya namah is one mantra for Sri Krishna. Again KLEEM HUM HREEM GUHYE KALIKE KLEEM KLEEM HUM HUM HREEM HREEM SWAHA is Sri Guhyakali mantra. Mantras of MANY OTHER DEITIES contain KLEEM.All the mantras came from Lord Shiva. Its ONLY the Guru who has the authority to decide for which devata he or she will use this or any beeja.

(Reference:SastramulakmBharatiya Shaktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das,, Vol. 1, page 388)